# Do we need "not reproducible" off-topic close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

A question [like this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63889/20449) is in my opinion of a very poor value for a future readers, because it is narrowed to just one application, to just one specific version of that application.

**In addition, described problem is not any more reproducible -- metioned application's developer has updated it and in new version the problem itself does not exist anymore** (assuming, that using *the official ways* -- Google Play -- you can only install the newest version of each application).

For questions like that (where OP gives himself his own answer and that answer is something like "problem solved, because..." and that reason causes problem to be not reproducible anymore) we have in Stack Overflow special close reason:

> **Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic** > *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner **unlikely to help future readers** (...).*

Shouldn't we have similar close reason here, assuming that this site is devoted to an operating system often being upgraded with a lot of applications, that are even more updated and that many questions my become obsolete, because of an update that fixes disputed problem.

Comment: Yeah...in the past we had used "Too Localized" for these, before it was removed from the list. Now we'd have to replace one of our other close reasons or ask SE to expand our list by one (we get 3 customs currently). I suppose another option would be to deal with these using the "Other" reason when we need to, since it may represent a small-ish proportion of questions that get closed. In any case, I agree with your analysis that questions of this nature have no lasting value.

Comment: @user981 Why comment, not an answer? :)